# Stretch an image by using just aspect ratio.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Is there a way to stretch an image to an aspect ratio?

i.e. $4:3$ to $16:9$, but where it wouldn't matter if the input is $16:9$ or $1920:1080$ ? ( essentially I don't want scale to be controlled by the inputs for the aspect ratio ).

Comment: What exactly do you call the input ? Do you realize that 16/9 and 1920/1080  are the same numbers ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, sorry, maybe it's a poorly phrased question. I just want to be able to stretch an image by each aspect, so if the current aspect ratio is 16:9 and the new ratio is 21:9 then it should only stretch along the x axis. ( It should stretch by the same amount if the new inputs are 2100 & 900 as if they were 21 & 9 ).

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. How would you know how 2100:900 relates to 4:3, for example ?

Comment: "if the current aspect ratio is 16 : 9 and the new ratio is 21 : 9 then it should only stretch along the x axis." What if the new ratio is 16 : 6.86? Then should it only squash along the y-axis? But 21 : 9 and 16 : 6.86 are the same ratio.

Comment: @Rahul If the new ratio is 16 : 6.86, where the old ratio was 16 : 9 , then it should still only stretch along the x axis.However if the new ratio is instead something like 14 : 9 , then it should stretch along the y axis.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't, that's why i've asked the question :) To see if there's a way to do it with the resultant ratio.

Comment: I can't answer as long as I don't understand the question. Can you provide a few clearly stated examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target ratio is $a:b$, store the ratio $r_t=a/b$. Similarly, let the aspect ratio of the current picture be $r_c$.

Then the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{r_t}{r_c}&0 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$ scales your $x$ coordinates so that the new image has the target aspect ratio.

You could do something simliar with the $y$ coordinate. It's all just simple scaling along one axis.

Comment: @Geoff It would just be $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{r_c}{r_t}\end{bmatrix}$